# How to redirect command output from docker container

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, output, stdout

Just another topic on this matter, but what's the best way of outputting docker container command STDOUT/ERR to a file other than running the command such as

```
bash -c "node cluster.js >> /var/log/cluster/console.log 2>&1"
```

What I don't like of the above is the fact that it results in 1 additional process, so finally I get 2 processes instead of 1, and my master cluster process is not the one with PID=1.

If I try

```
exec node cluster.js >> /var/log/cluster/console.log 2>&1
```

I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container node: 
exec: "node cluster.js >> /var/log/cluster/console.log 2>&1": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I am starting my container via docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
   node:
      image: custom
      build:
         context: .
         args:
            ENVIRONMENT: production
      restart: always
      volumes:
         - ./logs:/var/log/cluster
      command: bash -c "node cluster.js >> /var/log/cluster/console.log 2>&1"
      ports:
         - "443:443"
         - "80:80"
```

When I `docker-compose exec node ps -fax | grep -v grep | grep node` I get 1 extra process:

```
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 bash -c node cluster.js >> /srv/app/cluster/cluster.js
    5 ?        Sl     0:00 node cluster.js
   15 ?        Sl     0:01  \_ /usr/local/bin/node /srv/app/cluster/cluster.js
   20 ?        Sl     0:01  \_ /usr/local/bin/node /srv/app/cluster/cluster.js
```

As you can see, the `bash -c` starts 1 process which on the other hand forks the main node process. In docker container the process started by the `command` always has PID=1, that's what I want the node process to be. But it will be 5, 6, etc.

Comment: Have you tried using `bash -c "node cluster.js"` then you can access the logs by running `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414495/save-docker-compose-logs-to-a-file

Comment: None of these works for me. I just want to have the output printed in external files, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I managed to solve the issue by creating a bash file that starts my node cluster with `exec`:

```
# start-cluster.sh
exec node cluster.js >> /var/log/cluster/console.log 2>&1
```

And in docker-compose file:

```
  # docker-compose.yml
  command: bash -c "./start-cluster.sh"
```

Starting the cluster with `exec` replaces the shell with node process and this way it has always PID=1 and my logs are output to file.