# How to redirect all docker-compose logs automactically

Tags: node.js, docker, logging, docker-compose

I have node APIs and I run that with the help of docker-compose. I host that on EC2, so whenever I go and check for the logs I type `docker-compose logs` and it will give me all logs on the screen but how can I save all logs to the file **automatically**. What I mean is when I deploy new docker on the server then it should start saving all the logs to specific file so later I can go and check that out.

I can save docker-compose logs manually by executing this command:

```
docker-compose logs > logs.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save docker-compose logs to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414495/save-docker-compose-logs-to-a-file)

Comment: @mchawre in that answer they didn't talk about automatic logging. I want that only.

Comment: If you read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414495/save-docker-compose-logs-to-a-file properly, it states that the logs are already available in the file which you can get by running those command mentioned in that answer. You can also try to change your docker logging driver to `syslog`. Give it a try check this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a scheduled [crontab](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)

For example:

`0 1 * * * /bin/sh backup.sh`

---

In your case, I guess that will be something like this:

`0 1 * * * docker-compose logs > logs.txt`

You can also read more about crontabs [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/crontab-in-linux-with-examples/)