# How can I send and aggregate multiple docker container's logs to journald?

Tags: docker, logging

I'm running multiple containers that contain Apache. I'd like all these specific set of containers to log their log output to a single location - either a file or - or possibly journald?

Just some way in which I can aggregate their logs together - to be viewed together

---

I'm not looking for a heavy solution like fluentd / ELK stack.

How can I achieve the above? Currently all the containers are logging out to `/dev/stdout` and hence get collected in the 'docker logs'. But these are don't seem possible to aggregate together.

According to [Save docker-compose logs to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414495/save-docker-compose-logs-to-a-file) it seems I might be able to set a 'log path' - but how? Logging driver? And can this log file be shared between multiple containers?

Is the systemd logging driver a suitable option?

---

So I've had some luck with the `journald` logging driver. I've set some `labels` on a container like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx-lb:
    labels:
      - "node_service=nginx"
    logging:
      driver: "journald"
      options:
        labels: "node_service=nginx"
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

But now, how do I filter by these lables when viewing them with `journalctl`?

Here is an example journald entry generated:

```
{ "__CURSOR" : "s=b300aa41db4946f1bcc528e2522627ce;i=1087c;b=e6decf90a91f40c2ad7507e342fda85a;m=8744b1cdfa;t=5934bdb103a24;x=9ba66ecb768eb67", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1569328890657316", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "580973088250", "_BOOT_ID" : "e6decf90a91f40c2ad7507e342fda85a", "_MACHINE_ID" : "c1339882251041f48f4612e758675ff3", "_HOSTNAME" : "staging", "PRIORITY" : "6", "_UID" : "0", "_GID" : "0", "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "3fffffffff", "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : "unconfined\n", "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "system.slice", "_TRANSPORT" : "journal", "_PID" : "3969", "_COMM" : "dockerd", "_EXE" : "/usr/bin/dockerd", "_CMDLINE" : "/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock", "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/system.slice/docker.service", "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "docker.service", "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID" : "9f1488b462ae478a84bec6e64d72886b", "CONTAINER_NAME" : "3b9b51b4cda1a1e3b21a01f6fe80c7748fb3d231_apache_1", "CONTAINER_TAG" : "497b2f965b76", "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "497b2f965b76", "CONTAINER_ID" : "497b2f965b76", "CONTAINER_ID_FULL" : "497b2f965b767f897786f3bb8c4789dd91db1a91fe34e5ede368172f44fb3aac", "MESSAGE" : "192.168.240.1 - - [24/Sep/2019:12:41:30 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.0\" 200 2697 \"-\" \"curl/7.58.0\"", "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1569328890657297" }
```

Comment: Have you checked this: [Retrieve log messages with `journalctl`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/#retrieve-log-messages-with-journalctl)? Is the `CONTAINER_NAME` an option here?

Comment: I want to view/aggregate a SET of containers rather than a single one which I assume CONTAINER_NAME would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I instead used the `tag` logging option.

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx-lb:
    labels:
      - "node_service=nginx"
    logging:
      driver: "journald"
      options:
        labels: "node_service=nginx"
        tag: "nginx"
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

And then to view / filter:

```
journalctl CONTAINER_TAG=nginx  --since "1 hour ago"
```

Comment: could you expand on how this solves the issue of aggregating multiple container logs? when I assign the same tag foo and use `journalctl --since -1d CONTAINER_TAG=foo` it appears to be only outputting the log of the last created container with that tag

Answer (score 0):

I've met similar problem and this could probably work,

run `journalctl` command with option `CONTAINER_NAME` repeatedly, for example:

`journalctl -f CONTAINER_NAME=containerA CONTAINER_NAME=containerB`

will output recent logs from containerA and containerB.